# Replacement HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain() in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, httpruntime

Does anyone know if there is a replacement for `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()` in ASP.NET 5? I can't find `HttpRuntime` at all, is there going to be a function just like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to gracefully shutdown your app domain in ASP.NET 5 is by using: IApplicationShutdown. You could even use that in combination with an IFileWatcher and your own configuration files … if you really wanted to mimic an app domain restart by bumping/touching a file. See this blog post http://shazwazza.com/post/aspnet-5-re-learning-a-few-things-part-1/

From this link http://forums.asp.net/t/2051838.aspx?How+to+restart+Aso+Net+5+application  you can use something like below code to restart your application

```
 IApplicationShutdown _applicationShutdown;
    public AdminController(IApplicationShutdown applicationShutdown)
    {
        _applicationShutdown = applicationShutdown;
    }


    public IActionResult RestartApplication()
    {
        _applicationShutdown.RequestShutdown();
        ............
    }
```

For a deep dive into the ASP.NET 5 runtime, have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913182.aspx